# Read metadata of video like comment, author, etc

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, metadata, mp4

I have a video that I read with mp4box.js, and I’d like to get the metadata of this video in my browser, like comment, author, etc. (I’m mostly interested in comments, you can easily add them to a video in VLC by using the Ctrl-I shortcut). How could I do this?

Right now I can't find any direction on the internet. For now I only managed to correlate the size of the `moov > udta > meta > ilst` block in https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/test/filereader.html with the size of my comments but the binary content not really match so I guess there is another step of parsing, I’m unsure how to get that block, then how to parse it and it feels like a really complicated solution for such a simple task.

As explained in comment, the `mp4boxFile.onReady` does not provide user metadata:

[image]

but if I manually read the box `udta`, then I get some more information. Somehow, I found inside a subbox that contains the content, but it contains other information as well, so I need to know the encoding of that box to read it:

```
--> "hdlr" --> "mdir" --> "appl" --> "ilst" --> ©cmt.data:
Hey. I am a comment that I'd like to print in the browser. 
I might have json structure inside like ("Hey": [1,2.3]). 
R (or byte val: 0x52)
©nam
J (or byte val: 0x4A)
.dataBBH gravitational lensing of gw150914_comment_from_vlc.mp4% 

--> "©too" data: Lavf58.76.108 

--> "free"
```

here is the code I’m using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MP4 Metadata Extraction</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept=".mp4">
    <div id="metadataDisplay"></div>
    <script src="https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/dist/mp4box.all.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
          const reader = new FileReader();

          reader.onload = function (e) {
            const arrayBuffer = e.target.result;

            // Initialize mp4box
            const mp4boxFile = MP4Box.createFile();
            mp4boxFile.onReady = (info) => {
              console.log("READY");
              console.log(info);
            };
            mp4boxFile.onError = () => {
              console.log("Error");
            };
            // Create a Blob from the ArrayBuffer
            /* const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
             */
            console.log("created blob");

            // Read the Blob using mp4box
            arrayBuffer.fileStart = 0;
            mp4boxFile.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);

            // Get metadata
            const udtaBoxes = mp4boxFile.getBoxes("udta");

            const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
            udtaBoxes.forEach((box) => {
              console.log("Box ", box);
              box.boxes.forEach((subbox) => {
                console.log("Subbox", subbox);
                if (subbox.data) {
                  console.log(decoder.decode(subbox.data));
                }
              });
            });
          };

          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One of the principal reasons for downvoting is (from the tooltip of the downvote arrow): "This question does not show any research effort". Note that wording; The question does not *show* any research effort. *Not* "No research effort was made". Just that none was *shown*.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Usually people complain that I write too long texts… So I spent already a few hours on this without much success. Right now I only have managed to correlate the size of the moov > udta > meta > ilst block in https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/test/filereader.html with the size of my comments… but the binary does not exactly matches… but first I’m unsure how to get that block, then how to parse it… and it feels like a really complicated solution.

Comment: It looks like you wait for [the `onReady` callback to fire](https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/#onreadyinfo) and read the `info` it provides in that callback? I have no idea, but that's what 2 minutes of looking at the site got me.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If you try it you will see that this does not provide user-related metadata, only stuff like duration…

Answer (score 0):

> *"I found inside a subbox that contains the content, but it contains other information as well"*

**(1) Understanding your subbox `.data` input:**

Assuming this line: `console.log( decoder.decode(subbox.data) );` gives you the following example text:

```
Hey. I am a comment that I'd like to print in the browser. I might have json structure inside like {"Hey": [10,50,300]}.
```

Then it means your `subbox` variable's `.data` holds these byte values (as written in hex format):

```
48 65 79 2E 20 49 20 61 6D 20 61 20 63 6F 6D 6D 65 6E 74 20 74 68 61 74 20 49 27 64 20 6C 69 6B 65 20 74 6F 20 70 72 69 6E 74 20 69 6E 20 74 68 65 20 62 72 6F 77 73 65 72 2E 20 49 20 6D 69 67 68 74 20 68 61 76 65 20 6A 73 6F 6E 20 73 74 72 75 63 74 75 72 65 20 69 6E 73 69 64 65 20 6C 69 6B 65 20 7B 22 48 65 79 22 3A 20 5B 31 30 2C 35 30 2C 33 30 30 5D 7D 2E
```

Paste the above byte values into a **hex editor** to see the bytes decoded into a text String.

PS: You can check any byte's value (as hex) using `.toString(16)`:

```
alert("byte value is: " + "0x" + subbox_data[0].toString(16) );
```

**(2) Decoding the bytes into text and extract an Object from it:**

Your output String (from bytes/data) has quote marks, which is not allowed.

```
Not Allowed : var myStr = "this is a "quote" inside text"
Allowed     : var myStr = "this is a \"quote\" inside text"
```

You must **escape** the internal quote marks by adding a backslash `\` in front of each one.

Instead of using `decoder.decode(subbox.data)` you can **extract the embedded Object** using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

//# hold each byte value after converting it into a String character
var bytes_str = "";

//# Array to recreate your input: subbox.data ...
var subbox_data = [ 0x48, 0x65, 0x79, 0x2E, 0x20, 0x49, 0x20, 0x61, 0x6D, 0x20, 0x61, 0x20, 0x63, 0x6F, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x65, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x61, 0x74, 0x20, 0x49, 0x27, 0x64, 0x20, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x20, 0x74, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x70, 0x72, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x74, 0x20, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x74, 0x68, 0x65, 0x20, 0x62, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x77, 0x73, 0x65, 0x72, 0x2E, 0x20, 0x49, 0x20, 0x6D, 0x69, 0x67, 0x68, 0x74, 0x20, 0x68, 0x61, 0x76, 0x65, 0x20, 0x6A, 0x73, 0x6F, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x73, 0x74, 0x72, 0x75, 0x63, 0x74, 0x75, 0x72, 0x65, 0x20, 0x69, 0x6E, 0x73, 0x69, 0x64, 0x65, 0x20, 0x6C, 0x69, 0x6B, 0x65, 0x20, 0x7B, 0x22, 0x48, 0x65, 0x79, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x20, 0x5B, 0x31, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x35, 0x30, 0x2C, 0x33, 0x30, 0x30, 0x5D, 0x7D, 0x2E ];

for (let i = 0; i < subbox_data.length; i++) 
{
    //# replace any " (ie: quote_mark) with a \" (ie: back_slash + quote_mark)
    if( subbox_data[i] == 0x22 ) { bytes_str += ( "\"" ) }

    //# else use the given String value
    else { bytes_str += String.fromCharCode( subbox_data[i] ) }

}

alert("subbox_data text:" + "\n" + bytes_str );

var str_a = ( bytes_str.indexOf("{") - 1 );
var str_b = ( bytes_str.indexOf("}") + 1 );

var extracted_text_for_obj = bytes_str.slice( str_a, str_b );
alert("extracted text (makes new Object):" + "\n" + extracted_text_for_obj);

//# create Object from text that describes an Object setup
const obj_from_text = JSON.parse( extracted_text_for_obj );

//# object has one entry with label "Hey" which is a pointer for an Array
alert( 
        "new Object has these following entries/keys: " + Object.keys( obj_from_text ) + "\n" +
        "entries/keys: Hey contains Array of length: " + (obj_from_text.Hey.length) + "\n" +
        "Array[2] at this path... Object.Hey is: " + obj_from_text.Hey[2] 
    );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Where *"create Object from text that describes an Object"* means something like:

```
var myText = "{ ... }"; //# such String can be converted into an { } Object
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not really what I wanted for multiple reasons. First, you make many assumptions on the shape on my data. What if the comment has no brace? What if it contains utf-8 data, stored on multiple bytes? (For my precise use case, I actually already added a dummy string before and after like MYSTART/MYSTOP, and use regex groups+utf8 decoding to have the value in 2 lines, no need to escape quotes at all, or decode individual bytes, but I am interested by a more generic solution to get any title/comment).

Comment: Secondly, people here have been editing my original message replacing my screenshot with a text of my input, but they removed the content of the first bytes of the message…, which is the most important part. This part seems to encode information about the name of the field and its length, but the encoding is quite weird so reverse engeneering the format is not so easy. So I guess one needs to know exactly how these boxes are encoded to decode properly, but this information is surprisingly hard to find.

Comment: Actually I just realized that you were the one replacing my picture with a different textual data ^^

Comment: **(1)** _"No need to escape quotes at all, or decode individual bytes"_ Your MP4 file `.data` is in bytes, you have to **process it as bytes**. There are no shortcuts and using Regular Expressions will give you wrong results. You want **ASCII** decoding, not **UTF-8**. For example UTF-8 cannot decode byte `0xA9` giving incorrect `�` result but in ASCII the same byte will be correctly decoded into '©` symbol (as in how MP4 stores bytes for the '©cmt` box: `A9 63 6D 74`). **(2)** _"What if the comment has no brace?"_ then why show an example with braces and say this data is my problem?

Comment: **(3)** _"This part seems to encode information about the name of the field and its length, but the encoding is quite weird so reverse engeneering the format is not so easy."_ You are reading as UTF-8. Read the data as ASCII (decode each byte using `.toString` for the ASCII equivalent). Also some bytes represent a 32-bit (4-bytes) integer, not text characters. Does MP4Box tell you the offset of the comment box? If yes, use the array to extract (using Array's `.slice` option). I can help you with that if you know the offset.